# Convertir una columna en especifico de Double a Varchar

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo un sistema en el cual realizo una consulta, hago uso de un UNION para mostrar resultados de dos tablas simultaneamente, en la columna de precio de pr_gastos, los precios estan como double y deseo pasarlos a varchar.

```
String consulta = "  SELECT codigo,nombre,pago_parcial,pago_parcial,total "
                    + "FROM ptjs_accounted\n"
                    + "WHERE po = '" + field.getBuscar() + "'"
                    + "UNION SELECT  SUBSTRING(accountcode, 1,15), accountcode, coo,coo, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),precio,3)"
                    + "FROM pr_gastos \n"
                    + "WHERE idc = '" + field.getBuscar() + "'"
                    + "AND accountcode LIKE '2%'";
```

Intento hacer uso del convert para pasar de double a varchar los datos de precio de pr_gastos, pero me marca error, si me podrian asesorar, de antemano muchas gracias..

Comment: ¿Con qué fin buscas cambiar el tipo de datos?

Comment: ¿Probaste `CONVERT(precio, CHAR)` o con `CAST(precio AS CHAR)`? No se exactamente para que necesitarías convertirlo en la consulta cuando en java lo puedes convertir directamente de double a string, pero bueno, de que se puede hacer se puede hacer.

Comment: El total de la primer tabla ptjs_accounted en la bdd lo tienen como varchar y en el resultado de la consulta aparecia el resultado como caracteres que no tenian nada que ver con los resultados, creo que se debia porque el precio de la otra tabla a la que se le hace union l tipo de dato es double, pero ya con el CONVERT aparecen correctamente en la tabla los resultados, me funciono con CONVERT(precio, char) muchas gracias por su ayuda.